# Displaying a video stream to the oculus Rift

Tags: opencv, oculus

I'm trying to mod Oculus World Demo to show an video stream from a camera and not a pre-set graphic, however, I'm finding it difficult to find the proper way to render an cv::IplImage or cv::mat image type onto the Oculus screen. If anyone knows how to display an image to the oculus I would be very grateful. This is for the DK 2.

Answer (score 4):

Pure OpenCV isn't really well suited to rendering to the Rift, because you would need to manually implement the distortion mechanisms that are normally provided by the Oculus Rift SDK.

The best way to render an image from OpenCV onto the screen is to load the image into an OpenGL or Direct3D texture and use the 3D rendering API (GL or D3D) to place it into a rendered scene.  There is an [example](https://github.com/OculusRiftInAction/OculusRiftInAction/blob/master/examples/cpp/opencv/Example_13_2_SimpleWebcamDemo.cpp) of this in Github repository for [my book on Rift development](http://oculusriftinaction.com).

In summary, it sets up the video capture using the OpenCV API and then launches a thread which is responsible for capturing images from the camera device.  In the main thread, the draw call renders a simple 3D scene which includes the captured image.  Most of the interesting Rift related code is in the parent class, [RiftApp](https://github.com/OculusRiftInAction/OculusRiftInAction/blob/master/examples/cpp/common/Rift.cpp).

Comment: @Jherico The GitHub links in this post are no longer working.

Comment: There is this, "HighResWebcamDemo" : https://github.com/OculusRiftInAction/OculusRiftInAction/blob/master/examples/cpp/opencv/HighResWebcamDemo.cpp